# UML plugins in Netbeans6.8

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, netbeans6.8

Java: I tried to add the available plugins in netbeans6.8 but it ask for *.nbm file instead of jar files, Please guide me for the same and also provide the related download URL and steps for the same. I added this URL http://ea.ddns.com.br:8090/netbeans6.8/UML/catalog.xml in my Setting tab but still unable to find the plugins

Answer (score 1):

The UML plugin for the NetBeans IDE is available for until version 6.7. Support was dropped after that.

Comment: Although http://quality2.netbeans.org/dashboard/current/uml.html suggests they are working on getting UML in NetBeans 7.0.1. That would be great news!

Comment: Now that 7.0.1 is out, we still have to wait for UML coming back into the plugin repository... :-(

Comment: NetBeans UML plugins are available for various versions see http://netbeans.org/features/uml/

Answer (score 0):

I think UML was stopped after the 6.5 Netbeans release.
Download one of the previous build and you will be able to create diagrams.

You can also use Eclipse. The trick is to import your java project inside Eclipse and reverse engineer it in order to create diagrams. Once created you export your diagrams into image format such png, gif etc...Finally you copy your image into your netbeans project.
Nobody would ever guess that your diagrams are coming from Eclipse :-)